Delphi IOresult misbehaving
I have an application that saves data to an xml file but when data cannot be interpreted it writes a message to a textfile.  I am using Delphi 11, Windows 10, 64bit compilation
The procedure to write the message looks like this (Of course the NamedOPFile was created elsewhere and mostly works)
procedure WriteStrToNamedOPFile(var NamedOPFile: TextFile; TextString: string);
begin
{$I-}
  append(NamedOPFile);
{$I+}
  if IOResult = 0 then
  begin
    System.writeln(TextFile(NamedOPFile), TextString);
    closefile(TextFile(NamedOPFile));
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('LOG File write access error: IOResult = ' + inttostr(IOResult));
end;

Every now and then (ie not always) I get the following error message

LOG File write access error: IOResult = 0<

Which should not be possible as the IOResult is 0.
Could this be a timing issue to disk or something else?

It's been a while, but doesn't the first reference to IOResult clear it so that when you call it again in ShowMessage it's been reset to zero?

Why are you still using 1980's style file I/O? A TStringList, TStringStream, or TFileStream would be much better options. And why are you using IOResult instead of the exception system, which would give you a much better error message?

Thank you - I have just used stolen old code as we very seldom write to files now and have forgotten about the IOResult being reset.  Will probably rewrite the old unit with more modern code as per suggestion.

Accessing IOResult resets its value to 0. The proper way to do it would be more like this:
procedure WriteStrToNamedOPFile(var NamedOPFile: TextFile; TextString: String);
var
  Res: Integer;
begin
{$I-}
  Append(NamedOPFile);
{$I+}
  Res := IOResult;
  if Res = 0 then
  begin
    System.Writeln(TextFile(NamedOPFile), TextString);
    CloseFile(TextFile(NamedOPFile));
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('LOG File write access error: IOResult = ' + IntToStr(Res));
end;

